# How can update my code for a django app without earasing the existing database (Read Description)?

Tags: python, django, database, heroku, web

I have a python django application that I published to heroku by connecting to github. I want some people to be able to add some information to the database from the website. If I make changes to the code, push to github and deploy the branch the database will go back to how it was at first. How can update my code for the app without changing the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you host your database on a separate server, like with [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/) or [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), and configure your code to connect to this remote host, you should have sufficient decoupling to avoid what you are talking about.